# How to reset Excel internal button count?

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have an an Excel sheet that uses VBA to generate some form control buttons on the fly. 
the buttons are cleared and then new buttons are created. 
I have noticed that even though old buttons are deleted Excel is keeping an internal register of each button. New buttons have button name of over 11K

1. I don't know if there is some sort of limit excel will allow for this and I don't want to run out of buttons.
2. I am not sure if this growing registry of buttons past is causing the file size to grow.
3. I would like to be able to reset the increment back to 0

Anyone have any idea how I can go back to button_0 ? (without starting a whole new Excel sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems internal button count is sheet specific. Solution is to copy sheet, rename old sheet, then rename new sheet to old sheet name. Then delete old sheet. Viola! button count reset.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer somewhere in a forum, but I couldn't retrace it.
You could also pragmatically create the button by a function/sub-routine as a workaround.

Example: below function adds a button and limits the count to a fixed number (in my case, it is the total buttons available).

In my sheet, the first button is named "Button 687" (before I use the macro) and the second button is named "Button 2".

But, it is quite not dynamic when you want to add Drop Down or other form control etc. Macro recording helps you figure out the syntax, methods and properties of the form control you want to add though.

I am not sure why "buttons" is not listed in Properties/Methods after you typed "Activesheet." but Activesheet.Buttons(1).Name or Activesheet.buttons.add are valid codes.

```
Public Sub Add_Button(ButtonLabel$, ButtonSize#, BFontSize#, BFontName$)
    
    Dim Button__ As Object
    Dim One_Unit#: Per_Unit = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    
    'Creates a button at the sheet's first cell (row 1, col 1) with the height and width being 1cm. 
    
    Set Button__ = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, One_Unit, One_Unit)
    
    'button count will be restricted to the number set by user. 
    With Button__
        .Name = "Button " & ActiveSheet.Buttons.Count
        With .Characters
            .Text = UCase(BLabel)
            .Font.Name = BFontName
            .Font.Size = BFontSize
        End With
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

```
Sub AddAButton()

Add_Button BLabel:="SAVE"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Buttons(ActiveSheet.Buttons.Count).Name

End Sub
```